# listbox select count not work dont work

Tags: javascript, html

I recently trying to make a form with multiple select box. When someone select the options the number of selected options will be display on another text. I'm a beginner in JavaScript.

The function is called, but it doesn't count the number of the selected options.

```
<select name="element_17_1[ ]"
        size="7" multiple="multiple"
        class="element select medium"
        id="element_17_1[ ]"
        onfocus="selectCount(this.form);"
        onClick="selectCount(this.form);"
    >
    <option value="Opt1">Opt1</option>
    <option value="Opt2">Opt2</option>
    <option value="Opt3">Opt3</option>
    <option value="Opt4">Opt4</option>
    <option value="Opt5">Opt5</option>
    <option value="Opt6">Opt6</option>
    <option value="Opt7">Opt7</option>
</select>
```

and this is the function I tried in the `<head>`

```
function selectCount(f) {
    var selObj = myForm.elements['element_17_1[]'];
    var totalChecked = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
            totalChecked++;
        }
    }
    f.element_9.value = totalChecked;
}
```

Comment: I noticed your JavaScript function does not have a space between the square brackets `element_17_1[]`. Should this have a space like the name and id of your select element?

Comment: @ZhihaoJia: Yes, the space is the issue.  Both names have to match.  (The ID, not so much.  In fact, apparently the ID shouldn't have the brackets *or* spaces.  The only characters technically allowed are letters, digits, `.`, `:`, `_`, and `-`.)

Comment: @sadpcd–form controls don't need IDs, but they must have a name to be successful (i.e. be included in a submit). You can program the function so that the select element's name is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML you have:

```
> <select name="element_17_1[ ]"
>          size="7" multiple="multiple"
>          class="element select medium"
>          id="element_17_1[ ]"
>          onfocus="selectCount(this.form);"
>          onClick="selectCount(this.form);"
>      >
```

Note that in the listener, `this` references the element itself, so just pass that:

```
           onfocus="selectCount(this);"
           onClick="selectCount(this);"
```

So a reference to the element is passed directly to the function, which can be:

```
function selectCount(selObj) {

    // The following line isn't needed now
    // var selObj = myForm.elements['element_17_1[]'];

    var totalChecked = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        totalChecked += selObj.options[i].selected? 1 : 0;
    }
    // The next line needs the form, so

    selObj.form.element_9.value = totalChecked;
}
```

Now you don't care what the select element is called. :-)

#### Edit

To click `element_9` you might do:

```
<input name="element_9" onclick="
 this.value = selectCount(this.form['element_17_1[ ]']);
">
```

Then the function is modified to:

```
function selectCount(selObj) {
    var totalChecked = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        totalChecked += selObj.options[i].selected? 1 : 0;
    }
    return totalChecked;
}
```

Enough homework for now. ;-)

Comment: really thanx the code works
what code should i try if i want click the element_9 and get the number of selected items from element_17_1 list box

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to get an element named `element_17_1[]`, but your select box is named `element_17_1[ ]`.  JavaScript just sees the name as a bunch of characters, and that space makes a difference.

Comment: i cant remove the [] whithout that i cant call it in php 
foreach ($_POST['element_17_1'] as $names)

Comment: You don't have to remove the brackets -- just the space.  The extra space makes the name you're looking for different from the name of the element.  The two names should be identical, character for character.

Answer (score 0):

Change your select's name `name="element_17_1"`and id `id="element_17_1"` and in also you don't have `myForm` in your function so `var selObj = myForm.elements['element_17_1'];` should be `var selObj = f.elements['element_17_1'];` and also you can use only on event as follows

```
onChange="selectCount(this.form);"
```

instead of

```
onfocus="selectCount(this.form);"
onClick="selectCount(this.form);"
```

**Complete function:**

```
function selectCount(f) {
    var selObj = f.elements['element_17_1'];
    var totalChecked = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < selObj.options.length; i++) {
        if (selObj.options[i].selected) {
            totalChecked++;
        }
    }
    f.element_9.value = totalChecked;
}
```

**Update:**

For your `php script`you can keep your select's name `name="element_17_1[]"` and so in the function it should be `var selObj = f.elements['element_17_1[]'];` but without space like`[ ]`

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/Y4ptn/6/)

Comment: i cant remove the [] whithout that i cant call it in php 
foreach ($_POST['element_17_1'] as $names)